# How can I clear the localstorage when user close react application window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am developing a react-redux application where once the user logs in, I was to store some information about the user in local storage. This is so that I can easily retrieve the user information when they perform a action.

If the user close the browser window, I would like to clear all localstorage for the react application. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What you are describing is [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and browser itself will clear it

Comment: @charlietfl Nopes. sessionStorage will delete data even when the tab is closed

Answer (score 17):

You can just use the JS function :

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Firing the event on close of the window

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: where should I call this function? Because the user is closing the window, so I am not sure how react can detect that.

Comment: Probably that would be quite unpredictable. Is it possible to clear the storage when the user opens the website instead? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

Comment: Because, what if computer crashes - there would be no corresponding event triggered

Comment: you can attach this event on `window.onbeforeunload`

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko I agree with what you you are saying. If you make that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Will this clear entire localStorage or only my websites localStorage? Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel storage is domain bound. so only clears for that specific domain.

Answer (score 8):

You could consider using `Window.sessionStorage` instead of `Window.localStorage`.

Data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page

> session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over
>   page reloads. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: That works ONLY if you don't want to share data across tabs!

Comment: @AlyssonMyller what do you mean exactly? I am switching from using localStorage to sessionStorage to keep a login token, and it seems to keep awareness of that when I open another tab.

Comment: @JoeM The spec says sessionStorage doesn't persist between tabs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Thanks @Kieran101. I'm too late here

Answer (score 3):

You can use localStorage.clear but you have to watch for window close event. Another possible solution is you can use session storage so it will be available until your browser is open. After that session will be removed, so you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

To clear a `localStorage` data on browser close, you can use the `window.onunload` event to check for tab close.

```
window.onunload = () => {
   // Clear the local storage
   window.MyStorage.clear()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the NPM package [react-beforeunload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload)

### Implementing react-beforeunload on NextJS (Typescript)

On your main file (in NextJS world: _app.tsx) do the following:

```
...
import { Beforeunload } from 'react-beforeunload';

const removeApplicationData = () => {
    if (window) { // NextJS is ServerSideRendering, therefore the window-check.
        localStorage.clear();
    }
};

...

return (
    <Beforeunload onBeforeunload={removeApplicationData}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Beforeunload>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Took @BertC's answer but in the documentation there is a simpler way:
[react-beforeunload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload)

```
npm i react-beforeunload
npm install @types/react-beforeunload --save-dev
```

in app.tsx

```
import { useBeforeunload } from 'react-beforeunload';

useBeforeunload(() => {
if (window) localStorage.clear();
  });
```